# What is ngModel without [] and ()?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

what is ngModel without brackets and parentheses and when to use it?

```
<input name="name" ngModel>
```

I know [ngModel] is syntax for one-way bindning and [(ngModel)] is two-way bindning but what does it mean when you write without any brackets and parentheses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NgModel` is just a directive.
From Angular documentation:

> Creates a FormControl instance from a domain model and binds it to a
> form control element.

If you put it into HTML element, it just brings all methods of this class to the element. Thus means you can use it with your needs, for example get `change` event - `(ngModelChange)`.

Small example:

```
<input (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" ngModel />
```

This input has no initial value, but will emit event on change.

Comment: You may find a lot of useful examples: https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel

Comment: When you use ngForm, you can use ngModel without necessity of [(ngModel)], see the example in the [docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#listening-for-form-submission)

Answer (score -4):

<input name="name" [(ngModel)]="propertyName">

Comment: Reread the question. This does not answer it at all.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).